# i have wriiten a logout code in welcome.scala.html page but getting errors in that page how can i write the code for it

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, configuration, playframework-2.0

[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts0td.png) [sbt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg8Nv.png)

Cannot use a method returning play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder[play.api.mvc.Request,play.api.mvc.AnyContent] as a Handler for requests

I am trying to come back to the `index.scala.html` page after clicking on the logout button in `welcome.scala.html` but its showing a compilation error while executing.

**This is the `welcome.scala.html` page:**

```
<html>
    <body>
welcome to homepage
        <a href="@routes.HomeController.logout()">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout">
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is the `index.scala.html` page:**

```
@main("Welcome to Play") {
}
<html>
    <body>
        username<input type="text" name="uname">
        password<input type="password" name="pword">
        <a href="@routes.HomeController.welcome()">
            <div class="my-button">Submit</div>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is `HomeController`:**

```
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {
    def index = Action {
        Ok(views.html.index())
    }
    def welcome = Action
    {
        Ok(views.html.welcome())
    }
    def logout = Action
    {
        Ok(views.html.index())
    }
}
```

**This is the `routes` file:**

```
GET     /                                 controllers.HomeController.index
GET     /welcome                          controllers.HomeController.welcome
GET     /logout                           controllers.HomeController.logout




this is main.scala.html code


@(title: String)(content: Html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>@title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"media="screen"href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")">
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/hello.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
@content
</body>
</html>


got this error after editing the routes page
Cannot use a method returning play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder[play.api.mvc.Request,play.api.mvc.AnyContent] as a Handler for requests
```

Comment: what have you tried? what's the error?

Comment: i have taken a two text boxes and a submit button after clicking the submit button its open a new page(i.e welcome.scala.html page).. in that page i have logout button which must be return back to my index.scala.html page

Comment: still my issue wasn't solved could anyone kindly give solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you've got a small error on your routes file:

Change this:
`GET     /logout                 controllers.HomeController.index`

into
`GET     /logout                         controllers.HomeController.logout`

And it should just work.

Comment: got this error after updating routes file

Cannot use a method returning play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder[play.api.mvc.Request,play.api.mvc.AnyContent] as a Handler for requests

Comment: what version of play? can you edit your question with the full new error?

Comment: i have edited my question n i am using 2.6.2 version of play

Comment: your code works fine to me. does the error point to a specific route/controller method?

Comment: the error showing in sbt command prompt is unspecified value parameter hif

GET    /logout           controllers.HomeController.logout

Comment: Wait... what? Please update your question with the error you're getting. It's too confusing now. Is it "unspecified value..." or "Cannot use a method returning..."?

Comment: when i open in localhost:9000 its showing.... 1)Cannot use a method returning play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder[play.api.mvc.Request,play.api.mvc.AnyContent] as a Handler for requests

  2) But in sbt command prompt its showing unspecified value parameter and indicating routes/logout file

Comment: Please add screenshots

Comment: i have posted them plz check

Comment: Look... I'm trying this https://github.com/mfirry/so45668813 and it compiles just fine. Is this somehow similar to what you have? Please have a look.